# Trying to to print only even values of a column Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the dataframe:

```
exam_data  = {'name': ['Anastasia', 'Dima', 'Katherine', 'James', 'Emily', 'Michael', 'Matthew', 'Laura', 'Kevin', 'Jonas'],
        'score': [12.5, 9, 16.5, np.nan, 9, 20, 14.5, np.nan, 8, 19],
        'attempts': [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1],
        'qualify': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes']}
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

I'm trying to print only even values of a column named "attempts"
is there a function I can use?
such as:

```
df["attempts"].even()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
df.attempts[df.attempts % 2 == 0]
```

If you look at `df.attempts % 2 == 0`, you'll see it is a series of `True`s and `False`s. Then we use it as a boolean mask to select desired entries which give "0 as remainder when divided by 2" i.e., even ones.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by mask - compare modulo 2 with `0` and column name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(exam_data)

print (df.loc[df.attempts % 2 == 0, 'attempts'])
2    2
4    2
8    2
Name: attempts, dtype: int64
```

For odd values compare by `1`:

```
print (df.loc[df.attempts % 2 == 1, 'attempts'])
0    1
1    3
3    3
5    3
6    1
7    1
9    1
Name: attempts, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following:

```py
print(df[df['attempts']%2==0]['attempts'].values)
```